# MQTT Client subscribe to PostgreSQL DB Changes

Tags: java, postgresql, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a PostgreSQL DB that updates periodically, and want to publish the latest changes to a mosquitto broker.
What is the most elegant way to do this approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this idea is interesting i am using PostgreSQL 9.5 and in the console if i type CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu; the python language is available.
But how i can receive the whole database and the periodically changes of the database into my Broker.

```
CREATE FUNCTION publishChanges ()
  RETURNS integer
AS $$
  import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
  import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
  #client = mqtt.Client()
  #client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)

  publish.single("test/data", SELECT * from table ,hostname="127.0.0.1")

  #client.loop_forever()
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Comment: You can't publish a query like that. You should only publish the changed record, not the whole table. But the concept is roughly what I was suggesting

Comment: What is the return value of the function and how can can be the trigger statements implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

Postgress has its own publish/subscribe system: listen/notify. Set up the proper (listen)notify channels in postgress for the information you want published. The notify payload can be formatted as a mqtt message string. Create a client that listens to them and publishes to the  mqtt-broker.

Answer (score 0):

Postgress appears to support python [stored procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpython.html) which you should be able to call from a create/update trigger.

This combined with the paho python client would do what you want

Comment: Maybe so ? 

    CREATE FUNCTION publishChanges ()
      RETURNS integer
    AS $$
      import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
      import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
      #client = mqtt.Client()
      #client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
    
      publish.single("test/data", SELECT * from table ,hostname="127.0.0.1")
      
      #client.loop_forever()
    $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;